# AVAssetWriter::append() returns false with no extra info (How to do segmenting of captured input to video-chunks with AVFoundation?)

Tags: ios, avfoundation, video-capture, avcapturesession, avassetwriter

I am building a feature where I record video and audio using AVFoundation. I will record for hours, but I want to upload chunks to our backend so that we can build a live HLS-playlist (after som processing of the segments).

**First of all, is there a sample somewhere doing this? I haven't found any reference implementations so to say...**

Here is my take on it:

- It's pretty straight-forward to setup a `AVCaptureSession` following the docs and examples on the web.
- I implement `AVCaptureVideoDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate` and  `AVCaptureAudioDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate` to get access to the sample buffers
- I have two `AVAssetWriter`s and switch between, one with `mediaType` == `AVMediaTypeVideo` and one with `mediaType` == `AVMediaTypeAudio`.
- Using `CMSampleBufferGetOutputPresentationTimeStamp(sampleBuffer)` I switch between the writers after typically 5 seconds.

Problems:

1. Sometimes, the when calling `AVAssetWriter::append()`, it just fails
   and returns false
2. According to the documentation, one shall check `AVAssetWriter.status`.
   In this situation it is set to `AVAssetWriterStatusFailed` and more information should be available in `AVAssetWriter.error`
3. `AVAssetWriter.error` is set to
   `Optional(Error Domain=AVFoundationErrorDomain Code=-11800 \"The operation could not be completed\" UserInfo={NSUnderlyingError=0x14e73dc10 {Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=-16364 \"(null)\"},NSLocalizedFailureReason=An unknown error occurred (-16364), NSLocalizedDescription=The operation could not be completed})`
4. `AVFoundationErrorDomain.code` `11800` means `AVErrorUnknown`

Anyone that has had the same problems or knows how to find more info?

Finally, when I switch between writers, there is a period from when I call `AVAssetWriter.startWriting()` (I do this when I create my idle writer, before it its time to switch to a new segment) to when I have called `AVAssetWriter.startSession(atSourceTime: startTime)`. During this time I need to hold on to sampleBuffers (typically audio). I just make a copy

```
 var copiedBuffer: CMSampleBuffer?
 CMSampleBufferCreateCopy(nil, sampleBuffer, &copiedBuffer)
 guard copiedBuffer != nil else {
    throw VideoWriterError.failedToCopyBuffer
 }
 pendingSampleBuffers.append((isVideo, copiedBuffer))
```

After `AVAssetWriter.StartSession()`, I write them to the new writer:

```
    while !pendingSampleBuffers.isEmpty {
        let (isVideo, sampleBufferOpt) = pendingSampleBuffers.removeFirst()
        guard let sampleBuffer = sampleBufferOpt else {
            throw VideoWriterError.failedToCopyBuffer
        }
        try capturedFrame(sampleBuffer: sampleBuffer, isVideo: isVideo)
    }
```

Seems to work, but there is a lot of posts about copying is shallow. I wonder if that can be related to my problems? Sample buffers exist in some kind of pool?

Comment: From a quick look this seems like its a queue issue, have you followed the rosyWriterSwift example, this has good info on the queues you should setup and use get it working perfect: 
https://github.com/ooper-shlab/RosyWriter2.1-Swift

Answer (score 2):

> If false is returned, clients can check the value of the AVAssetWriter
>   status property to determine whether the writing operation completed,
>   failed, or was cancelled.  If the status is failed, The AVAssetWriter
>   error property will contain an instance of NSErrorß that describes the
>   failure.

From [`append(_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avassetwriterinput/1389566-append).

I hope this helps. Please do comment for improvements.